# How can I transform a list of tuples into a pandas dataframe so that the first value of each tuple represents a column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested, tuples

I would like to transform my list of tuples so that the first element of each tuple represents 2 different columns. The second element of each tuple should represent the values that correspond to the columns in the pandas df.

My current list of tuples:

---

```
list_tuples = [('G', 9.8), ('B', 4.2), ('G', 9.6), ('B', 2.3), ('G',7.6), ('B', 3.1)]
```

---

Desired output:

---

```
            G        B   
           9.8      4.2      
           9.6      2.3      
           7.6      3.1
```

---

The code I currently have which does not give desired output:

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_tuples, columns=['G', 'B'])
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for convert list of tuples for dictionary of lists and then pass it to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in list_tuples:
    d[a].append(b)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
     G    B
0  9.8  4.2
1  9.6  2.3
2  7.6  3.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a dictionary, create your dataframe and clean it up with `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` and `DataFrame.bfill`:

```
list_tuples = [('G', 9.8), ('B', 4.2), ('G', 9.6), ('B', 2.3), ('G',7.6), ('B', 3.1)]

df = (pd.DataFrame([{col1:val} for col1, val in list_tuples])
        .bfill()
        .drop_duplicates('B')
        .reset_index(drop=True)
     )
```

```
     G    B
0 9.80 4.20
1 9.60 2.30
2 7.60 3.10
```