# Construct a pandas dataframe from a list of nested tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of tuples that looks like:

```
data = [('x', [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]),
        ('y', [('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6)])]
```

I want to build a dataframe that looks like the one below from it:

```
A  B  C
x  a  1
x  b  2
x  c  3
y  d  4
y  e  5
y  f  6
```

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568037/create-a-dataframe-form-a-list-of-tuples) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59436950/how-can-i-transform-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-pandas-dataframe-so-that-the-first-v)
but they don't produce what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a list of tuples(with the rows) and pass it to `pd.DataFrame` class (with `columns` argument as `["A", "B", "C"]`)

```
>>> data = [
...     ("x", [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]),
...     ("y", [("d", 4), ("e", 5), ("f", 6)]),
... ]
>>>
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     [(i, *k) for i, j in data for k in j],
...     columns=["A", "B", "C"],
... )
>>> print(df)
   A  B  C
0  x  a  1
1  x  b  2
2  x  c  3
3  y  d  4
4  y  e  5
5  y  f  6
```